# Cannot install ubuntu 21.04 on pc with nvidia rtx 3060ti

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, nouveau

I tried to install Ubuntu on my new PC with a Nvidia RTX 3060ti card installed. The installation hangs directly after modesetting to higher resolution with a unreadable screen for about 2 minutes. Then the ubuntu startup screen appears and nothing more happens. When pressing the ESC-button some kernel messages appear.
The last being

```
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: [drm] fb0: nouveaudrmfb frame buffer device
[drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
```

after that only

```
stdin: Invalid argument
```

and that's it.
When starting the PC with a gentoo USB stick, the PC starts normal, using the vesafb framebuffer.

Is there a way to force the installer use the vesafb framebuffer instead of the nouveaudrmfb or any other way to install Ubuntu on this specific PC?

Comment: Are you  sure the write to media was valid; ie. did you switch to terminal & check for issues; as the issue you describe can also occur on a faulty ISO download (did you verify that?) or faulty write to your installation media (ie. did you check the automatic validation of that?)

Comment: The write to media is valid. Installation works with exact the same USB stick on other computers with older hardware. Also tried to start with Ubuntu server and Kubuntu on this PC. Always the same result

Comment: Use safe graphics or `nomodeset` for the live session and installation. Don't forget to select the option for 3rd party drivers, etc. in order to have the correct Nvidia drivers installed from the start. Don't forget to disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: Already tried the boot option with nomodeset. Then I get the installer screen and after that nothing happens any more. No way to change to a screen or anything else. Secure Boot in UEFI is disabled

Comment: Another question: Has anybody already successfully installed Ubuntu 21.04 with an RTX 3060ti installed and active in his pc? Should it work out of the box?